# Use weight inside column (scrollable)

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a column which contains a spacer with weight 1f. The weight works when the column is not scrollable. I want the spacer to fill the available space.

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background)
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
) { MyItem() Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) MyItem() }
```

Comment: That's never going to work. A vertically scrollable column has no maximum height, so there's no such thing as "the available space". Consider other options, such as an `Arrangement.spacedBy` or an `Alignment.Bottom`.